# Using VS2010 online template "WPF MVVM project template", CanExecuteChanged not working?

Tags: wpf, templates, mvvm, canexecute

I created a new WPF MVVM application via Online Templates->WPF in VS2010->WPF MVVM project template.  I created a checkbox labeled "Refresh Enabled?" next to the "Refresh" button that I wanted to enable/disable the "Refresh" button when clicked.  I bound the `IsChecked` property of my checkbox to `aMainWindowViewModel` property I called `CanRefreshDate`, and it raises `RaisePropertyChanged(()=>CanRefreshDate);` in its setter.  Also in the `MainWindowViewModel`, I added my newly created `CanExecuteRefreshDate()`, which returns the bool of `CanRefreshDate` property.  However, when I click the checkbox, the button "Refresh" is never enabled/disabled to match.  What is the proper way to fix this, and is this an oversight in the template or what?

Here's my modifications to the template code:

Xaml:

```
<CheckBox Content="Refresh Enabled?" 
          IsChecked="{Binding CanRefreshDate}"/>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
private bool _CanRefreshDate;
public bool CanRefreshDate
{
    get { return _CanRefreshDate; }
    set
    {
        if (_CanRefreshDate != value)
        {
            _CanRefreshDate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CanRefreshDate);
        }
    }
}

public ICommand RefreshDateCommand { get { return new DelegateCommand(OnRefreshDate, CanExecuteRefreshDate); } }

private bool CanExecuteRefreshDate()
{
    return CanRefreshDate;
}
```

I noticed that the template had `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` misspelled `RasieCanExecuteChanged()` in DelegateCommand.cs and changed that. I was able to get it all working by removing `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` and modifying the

```
public event Handler CanExecuteChanged;
```

to :

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

However, I would like to know what the proper solution for this is and why the template doesn`t work.  Am i missing something, doing something wrong or what?  Please create a new solution and use the template I did and tell me what is going on!  Thanks!

Comment: the author responded and released version 4.1 of this built in template that fixes the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author fixed the issue and released version 4.1 of the template yesterday.

Comment: yep he emailed me when he fixed it and said thanks for pointing this out